# Unable to create AWS data pipeline for copying s3 to redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I am new to AWS, im trying to create a data pipeline to transfer s3 files into redshift.

I have already performed the same task manually. Now with pipelining, I am unable to proceed further here

**Problem with Copy Options :**

[image]

Sample data on s3 files is like :

```
15,NUL next, ,MFGR#47,MFGR#3438,indigo,"LARGE ANODIZED BRASS",45,LG CASE
22,floral beige,MFGR#4,MFGR#44,MFGR#4421,medium,"PROMO, POLISHED BRASS",19,LG DRUM
23,bisque slate,MFGR#4,MFGR#41,MFGR#4137,firebrick,"MEDIUM ""BURNISHED"" TIN",42,JUMBO JAR
24,dim white,MFGR#4,MFGR#45,MFGR#459,saddle,"MEDIUM , ""PLATED"" STEEL",20,MED CASE
```

So at manual work I gave this copy command:

```
copy table from 's3://<your-bucket-name>/load/key_prefix' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<Your-Access-Key-ID>;aws_secret_access_key=<Your-Secret-Access-Key>' 
csv
null as '\000';
```

and it worked perfectly

I tried with basic options as :

```
 1. csv
 2. null as '\000'
```

But none works.

Comment: Are you saying that your problem is the "JDBC Connection String"? You can copy that from the Redshift management console.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hey bro thanks you cleared my view. thanks a lot.